# Console app doesn't print when executing with xp_cmdshell under sql server agent proxy

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, proxy, xp-cmdshell

I have a requirement to automatically print an ssrs report to a specific printer on the network whenever a new row is inserted into a database table.  There is a trigger on the database table which uses xp_cmdshell to call a console application which renders and prints the report.  When I execute the console application from the command prompt it works.  Also, when I change the account that sql server runs as to administrator, xp_cmdshell works as expected and the report is printed.  But, I do not want sql server to run as administrator so I set up a proxy account, using sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account. I used administrator as the account that SQL Server executes xp_cmdshell as and set SQL Server to run as Local System.  However, when I log into SQL Server with an account that is not sysadmin and execute the console app with xp_cmdshell the console app generates the following exception:

The RPC server is unavailable - Source:System.Drawing - Stack Trace: at System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController.OnStartPrint(PrintDocument document, PrintEventArgs e) at System.Windows.Forms.PrintControllerWithStatusDialog.OnStartPrint(PrintDocument document, PrintEventArgs e) at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController.Print(PrintDocument document) at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument.Print() at PrintQCChecklist.Program.Main(String[] args)

I then called whoami.exe with xp_cmdshell and it returns 'administrator'.  Why would a document print when sql server is running as admin but crash when running under a proxy as admin???  (Please do not bite my head off for using xp_cmdshell.  I am aware of the security risks.  Thank you.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about publishing the SSRS reports to a network share, and have a printer program pick up the report, print it, and then archive it? I used to do something similar with a cheap third party printing tool - supported by the vendor, and - in my mind - cleaner.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I am definitely interested in exploring alternatives at this point.  Was there any time delay with your set-up?  The report needs to print, more or less, instantaneously.  Also, what 3rd party printing tool did you use?